# How can I scale my table view cell based on the size of my image in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

[image: Image of blank space]
So I am creating a social media type app where you can upload photos and text. Some of the posts have an image and others don't. My problem is trying to scale my imageview based on if there is a picture or not. It works fine when a photo is used but when there is no photo there is a giant blank white space i wanna get rid of. (See photos) Right now I have the image view set to a 1:1 ratio in the storyboard with no width or height constraints

```
if(posts[indexPath.row].url2 != ""){
     cell?.postImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: posts[indexPath.row].url2)    
}else{
     cell?.postImage.image = nil
}
```

Comment: Please share relevant code as a [example].

Comment: Why don't you add a default picture like facebook does for example? https://lh5.ggpht.com/_S0f-AWxKVdM/S5TpU6kRmUI/AAAAAAAAL4Y/wrjx3_23kw4/s72-c/d_silhouette%5B2%5D.jpg?imgmax=800

Comment: If there is no image then reduce the size of the cell  and put height constraint of image = 0